# Windows Phone - C# - Formatting DateTime correctly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime, datetime-format

In my application I have a procedure which sets a reminder on the phone for any given time. However I have a problem with formatting the date and time correctly.

I have two strings one with the date in either dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy format, and another string with the date in 24hour format.

How can I format these two strings into `DateTime`? I've tried `DateTime.Parse(date+time);` but that doesn't work.

Here's the full set of code:

```
public void setReminder(string fileTitle, string fileContent, string fileDate, string fileTime)
        {
            string dateAndTime = fileDate + fileTime;

            if (ScheduledActionService.Find(fileTitle) != null)
                ScheduledActionService.Remove(fileTitle);
            Reminder r = new Reminder(fileTitle)
            {
                Content = fileContent,
                BeginTime = DateTime.Parse(fileDate+fileTime),
                Title = fileTitle
            };
            ScheduledActionService.Add(r);
        }
```

Thank you, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe fileDate + " " + fileTime? The way you're combining them it'll look like 01/01/200023:00:00.  Need a space there.

Comment: That didn't work, resulted in error later on.

Comment: If it could be either dd/MM or MM/dd and you don't know for sure which then you can't reliably parse the date. Which month is 12/11 in? November or December? I expect it matters and you can't know unless you know which format it is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)).

```
string dateAndTime = fileDate + " " + fileTime;
string pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

Reminder r = new Reminder(fileTitle)
{
    Content = fileContent,
    BeginTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateAndTime, pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    Title = fileTitle
};
```

Make sure the pattern matches your date & time pattern. To separate the date and time I added a space just like there is one in my pattern.

For full list of specifiers: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks ill try that in a minute but what do I do about the date as it could be in either European or American format so I wouldn't be able to specify the format under the method you suggested?

Comment: You can't know that. if we take the date: 03/06/2013 can you tell me if it is 3 june or 6 march? If you can't tell me, how can the computer know?

Comment: I'll use the format MM/dd/yyyy I guess then, thanks for all the help!

Comment: No problem, If any other questions, just make a new question here :p